# element.style.display="" not revealing div (there's also a parent div)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I think I might be lacking understanding of div relationships?

Ultimately, the goal is to make the "element" div slide down ON TOP of the blue "parent" div.

Bu the current focus is to simply make it display (display was originally set to 'none').

I'm not sure why this isn't working:

```
<style type="text/css">
#parent {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#element {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    display: none;
}
</style>

  <body>
<div id="element"></div>
    <div id="parent" onclick="peekDown('element');"> </div>
  </body>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function peekDown(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.style.display = "";
    console.log(element.style.display);
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

On the assumption of no other errors, the following:

```
function peekDown(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.style.display = "";
    console.log(element.style.display);
}
```

can't work, because while `element.style.display = '';` will un-set the `display` property found in the `style` attribute, it *won't* unset, or affect, the `display` property as set in the stylesheet.

Therefore, you'd need to explicitly use `display = 'block';`:

```
function peekDown(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.style.display = "block";
    console.log(element.style.display);
}
```

You could, instead, change the `className` of the elment in order to `display` the element:

```
function peekDown(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.className = "newClass";
    console.log(element.style.display);
}
```

Which relies on an explicit CSS declaration for that `.newClass`:

```
.newClass {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `.style.display` property to `""` removes any inline style for that property (your code doesn't have any inline style) and lets rules in the stylesheet apply.

Modify the `.className` property instead and have `#element {}` and `#element.someDescriptiveClass {}` in your stylesheet.